# How to share a Docker container folder when it is not empty?

Tags: drupal, docker, drupal-8

I'm new to docker/drupal and I'm having a problem when creating a container using the drupal image:

https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/

The folder I would like to share (/var/www/html) with my host machine is not empty. It is where Drupal is installed. However, my folder in the host machine is empty ($HOME/site/drupal8) and the mountpoint replaces the content on the container folder. As a result, the Drupal content disappears.

I know it is a normal behavior when using mountpoints. However, I would like to know how developers do to be able to change the code on the container locally.

This is the command I am using:

```
docker run -d -P -v $HOME/site/drupal8:/var/www/html --name drupal8 drupal
```

By the way, is this the right way to start developing with Drupal? Or should I use an empty Docker (only LAMP) and install drupal locally in a shared folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you start from apache image, You'll just spend time to reinventing the wheel, and at the end, you will still have same issue.

I saw different solution, not directly linked to your drupal problematic, but here is some clues.

**First Solution (for development):**
The simpliest of my view, you have to retrieve drupal folder on you host. Whether you can download it from the internet, whether you have to retrieve from your image drupal.

To retrieve file from you image, run container without any volume mounted, retrieve folder with [docker cp command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

Once you retrieve folder on your host, launch container with volume

**Seconde solution**

I saw solution mounting volume /var/www/html**_ref** containing only overloaded files.

Image is modified to make a copy from this folder to container folder on first running.

Jenkins image use this to add plugin to default directory.

**Third solution (for production)**

Create your own dockerfile from drupal image. ADD your custom /var/www/html to your image.

In this solution, you will build new image (taggued) for each version or your script.

**Conclusion**

It's difficult to have same image for development and production. If you need to sync directory with our IDE, I recommand to use volume (first solution).